# Magento2, define variable in html (Knockout) file

Tags: magento2, html, knockoutjs

Consider below code, the condition `ko if: falg`  does not work. How to define variable `falg = "false"` in this file?

```
<!-- ko falg = "false" --> <!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
    <!-- ko falg = "true" --> <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko --> 
<!-- ko if: falg -->
...
<!-- /ko -->
```

update: I'm writing module to customize the minicart content. Below is the structure:

```
   registration.php
    |   
    +---etc
    |   |   module.xml
    |   |   
    |   \---frontend
    |           di.xml
    |           
    +---Plugin
    |       DefaultItem.php
    |       
    \---view
        +---frontend
            \---layout
            |     checkout_cart_sidebar_item_renderers.xml
            |       
            \---web
              \---js
                 \---myscript.js
              \---template
                 \---minicart
                    \---item
                            default.html 
    \---requirejs-config.js
```

So now my challenge is to pass the `flag` from `myscript.js` to based on the item attibute `product_has_url` to `default.html`

myscript.js ?

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'sidebar'
], function (Component, customerData, $, ko) {


    function checkAttr() {


    }

    return Component.extend({

        }); 

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
<!-- ko if: falg -->
...
...
<!-- /ko --> 
<!-- ko ifnot: falg -->
...
...
<!-- /ko -->
```

In js file you can use like this :

```
 return Component.extend({.....}),
    initObservable: function () {
        var me = this;
        me.flag(true);
        return this;
    }, ....
```

After this you need to deploy static content or to test you can add changes directly in the same `js` and `html` file of `pub/static`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept as answer but pls complete it with js script you mentioned. As the main issue is with assigning value to variable based on condition in ko template ;)

Comment: The js file is dependent on your module which you are using.

Comment: Isn't the path in namesapce/moudlename/view/frontend/web/js/myscript.js ?

Comment: I updated the question, pls let me know if you can help me with the js content in details. tnx